# how to use html input form in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

How can I input values from an HTML form in django. I am new to django and trying to make a clone of social network. I am not sure what code to write for forms.py,views.py, urls.py and models.py in order to input data.
Also, I have various fields in html form like textbox, check box , radio buttons. 
How to input data from these fields to the backend ?

html

```
<form method = 'POST' id = "new_post" action = "/posts/new/">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label>Title</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Enter title">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label>Situation Description</label><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the situation description"></textarea>

</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label>Outcome Description</label><br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="70" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the outcome description"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<label>Outcome Type</label><br>
<select id="inputO_type" class="form-control">
<option>Positive</option>
<option>Neutral</option>
<option>Negative</option>
</select>
</div>

<br>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
<div class="multiselect">
<div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">

    <option>reviewed?</option><select></select>

  <div class="overSelect"></div>
</div>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <label for="one">
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />Commissioning</label>
  <label for="two">
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />Construction</label>
    </div>
     </div></div>

    <div class="form-row">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Tags</label><br>
    <select id="inputTag" class="form-control">

      <option selected>Algorithms</option>
      <option selected>Architecture</option>
      <option selected>Automobile</option>
     <option>...</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <form method="post" action="#">

  <div>

  <input type="checkbox" name="FormStuff" id="FormStuff" required>
  <label for="FormStuff">Can't find your tag?</label>
  <div class="reveal-if-active">
   <label for="which-tag">Please fill in your desired tag below</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="which-tag" name="which-tag" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-tags-typetags">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Tag">
    <form method="post" action="#">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <br>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label>Does this warrant a process improvement action?</label>
    <div class="form-check">
  <input type = "radio" class="form-check-input" value="" class="form-control">
      <label>Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
  <input type = "radio" class="form-check-input" value="" class="form-control">
      <label>No</label>
    </div>
   </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the Django tutorial exercises?

Answer (score 2):

As some people suggested above, you need to learn more about Django, the documentation is very understandable. It's possible to let Django renders the form, [Django Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/)

To answer your question, you can simply add `name` attribute to the tag, and you will be able to retrieve it in the backend with `request.POST.get('name')` for post request, and `request.GET.get('name')` for get request. for instance

```
<form action='url' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}

    <textarea name='description' rows="4" cols="70" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the situation description"></textarea>
    <select id="inputO_type" name='inputO' class="form-control">
          <option>Positive</option>
          <option>Negative</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

In the backend:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    description = request.POST.get('description')
    inputO = request.POST.get('inputO')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Django documentation they have a specific section for building forms using Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

In the simplest context your form class will look something like this:

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

If you read through the rest of the django documentation they have step by step instruction on how to create a form using HTML and django.