# how to create a custom user registration form without using django's forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm working on a project back-end with another developer working on the front-end.

The front-end developer created a registration page with `html forms` and having trouble working with this type of form as I have only used django forms.
I cannot save the forms he created in the database.
Could somebody help me with this please.

I tried the django forms method but that doesn't work.

views files:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from user.forms import *  # Pour importer tous les elements du fichiers forms.py
# on import View pour utiliser la vue basée des classes.
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf import settings
from command.models import Command,CommandProduct
from main.utils import get_command_data
from main.models import Cart
from user.forms import *




class Loginpage(View):
    template_name = 'user/loginpage.html'
    form_class = 'LoginForm'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        message = ''
        print('-----------LOgiN GET-----------')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'message': message})
    

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        print('-----------LOgiN-----------')
        print(form)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('main/home')

            else:
                message = 'Identifiants invalides'

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'message': message})


def connect(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    error = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        print('-----------LOgiN-----------')

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                response = redirect('account')
                try:
                    if user.cart:
                        response.set_cookie('cart_id', user.cart.id)
                        return response
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'erreur on get cart on login: {e}')
                    if request.COOKIES.get('cart_id'):
                        cart = Cart.objects.get(
                            id=request.COOKIES.get('cart_id'))
                        if not cart.user:
                            cart.user = user  # cart.user = user
                            cart.save()
                            response.set_cookie('cart_id', cart.id)
                            return response
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        pass
                    cart = Cart.objects.create(user=user)
                    response.set_cookie('cart_id', user.cart.id)
                    return response
        else:
            error = 'Identifiants invalides'

    return render(request, 'user/loginpage.html', {'form': form, 'error': error})
```

html files :

```
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 offset-xl-2">
                <div class="axil-signin-form-wrap">
                    <div class="axil-signin-form">
                        <h3 class="title">Je suis Nouveau</h3>
                        <p class="b2 mb--55">Entrez vos détailles ci-dessous</p>
                        <form class="singin-form" method="post">
                            {% if form.errors %}
                            {{ form.errors }}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nom d'utilisateur</label>
                                <input name='username' type="text" class="form-control"
                                    value="anniemario">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input name="email" type="email"  class="form-control" 
                                    value="annie@example.com">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Numero de telephone</label>
                                <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control"  value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Pays</label>
                                <section><input name="country" type="text" class="form-control"></section>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Mot de passe</label>
                                <input name="password" type="password"  class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Confirmer le Mot de passe</label>
                                <input name="password2" type="password"  class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label>Adresse</label>
                                <input name="adress" type="text"  class="form-control" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="axil-btn btn-bg-primary submit-btn">Créer Un
                                    Compte</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

user models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    profil_photo= models.ImageField()

    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username} ({self.email})'
```

forms files:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50, label="mot de passe ", widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone', 'country',)
```

urls files:

```
from user import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('connexion/', views.connect, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logouts, name='logout'),
    path('update_password/', views.password, name='password'),
    path('', views.account, name='account'),
    path('favorites/', views.favorites, name='favorites'),
    path('upload_profile_photo/' ,views.upload_profile_photo , name='upload-profile'),
    path('<int:id>/detail_commands/',views.detail_command, name='detail-commands'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mentioned what is the error that was raised. Here is my take on the question.

Using Django Forms or HTML forms should not be any different.

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'phone', 'country',)
```

When you create a django form, it just creates a html element like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="id_username">
<input type="email" name="email" id="id_email">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="id_phone">
<input type="text" name="country" id="id_country">
```

So you can just make sure the name attribute of the element is same as the model attribute name. And you can create your own form in forms.py as you have already done.

And in your views:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
            return redirect("home")
```

If you completely want to skip forms.py, then you can manually create save form creating instances like:

```
if request.method == "POST":
  username = request.POST.get("username")
  email= request.POST.get("email")
  phone= request.POST.get("phone")
  country= request.POST.get("country")

  User.objects.create(
    email=email, username=username, phone=phone, country=country
  )
```

Please check this out as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404014/10669512

Comment: can you explain to me a little about the last part of which django does not manage the forms because in this project it is not me who manage the forms it is the html forms

Comment: so if I understand correctly, if I create a form with django forms I can place it in an html? if so how?

Comment: actually, you don't need to place your django forms in html. Front end developer can create their own html form. You just need to make sure they are passing {% csrf_token %} after form and the form input elements must have the same "name" attribute as your model attribute if you will be using django forms.. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: j'ai pu résoudre ça grâce à vous merci beaucoup